# when initializing PDO - should I do: charset=UTF8 or charset=UTF8MB4?

Tags: mysql, pdo, character-encoding

when initializing PDO - should I do: charset=UTF8 or charset=UTF8MB4 ?

here's my intialization:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=example.com;dbname=testdb;port=3306;charset=UTF8';
$dbh = new \Pdo($dsn, 'username', 'pass');
$dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

But should dsn be this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=example.com;dbname=testdb;port=3306;charset=UTF8MB4';
```

if mysql database has a default charset UTF8MB4.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should use **utf8mb4** for PDO and your database structures.

```
$dsn='mysql:host=example.com;dbname=testdb;port=3306;charset=utf8mb4';
```

When possible, don't forget to set the character encoding of your pages as well. PHP example:

```php
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
```